# hook audio streams on microphone devices in C

Tags: c, audio, stream, hook

I want to hook audio streams that come in microphone devices, then modify it before other processes, and then pass it to go.
my language is c .
is there any method to do this on windows or linux?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please show your efforts to the community

Comment: thanks jim, currently i need a solution for my scenario, i will glad to help others too.